# NServiceBus 4.03, performance counters number of msgs successfully processed not being updated

Tags: nservicebus, performancecounter, nservicebus4

I cant see any activity in # of msgs successfully processed.
I can see critical time being updated properly

Comment: I've checked and everything seems ok with version 4.1.1. Can you upgrade and see if that work?

Comment: The only problem is with the upgrade is my application is going live in couple of days and I can can't take a risk.

Comment: Can you run the Install-NServiceBusPerformanceCounters powershell command and see if that fixes things? What profile are you running?(make sure its nservicebus.production)

Comment: I am using some custom, worker and performance profile.